# Programmatically Create and Push View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating and pushing a view controller on a button touch using the below code as a utility method attached to the button

```
 func createSmartController() -> UIViewController{

    //Create controller and get view
                var controller = UIViewController()
                var view = controller.view
                var tag:String
                var count = 0

                //Create and layout scroll view
                var scrollView = UIScrollView()
                scrollView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                view.addSubview(scrollView)
                view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

                //Create and add content view
                var scrollContent = UIView()
                scrollContent.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                scrollView.addSubview(scrollContent)
                scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollContent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollContent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollContent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollContent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollContent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollContent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

                //Create all buttons
                var buttons = self.GetMyButtons() //Just returns and array of UIButtons

                //Add buttons to view with constraints
                var prevButton:String
                var constH:NSArray
                var constV:NSArray
                var hString:String
                var vString:String
                var index = 0
                for button in buttons{
                    button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                    scrollContent.addSubview(button)
                    button.bounds.size.height = 90
                    scrollContent.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollContent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                    scrollContent.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollContent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
                    if(index == 0){
                        scrollContent.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollContent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0))
                    }
                    else{
                        scrollContent.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: buttons[index-1], attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0))
                    }
                    if(index == buttons.count-1){
                        scrollContent.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollContent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8.0))
                    }
                    index++
                }
return controller
    }
```

This method is used in the below call to generate and push the view controller on button touchupinside

```
var controller = button.getSmartController()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

However, my view controller that is pushed seems to have no view at all. It is black/blank. The push animation also seems to have a slight hitch.

Comment: I don't see any objective-c here. Wrong tag?

Comment: @CrimsonChris I accept swift and objective-c for most of my ios stuff since the translation is easy.

Comment: You are asking for help debugging Swift code. Please don't use the objective-c tag for that.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I'll accept help using either language.

Comment: Your createSmartController function doesn't have a return value.

Comment: @killbros Apologies. That was a copy paste mistake. I've fixed it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All background colors were non-existant and showing as black. When programmatically creating elements, the styling must be added as well or all defaults will return as null/black.

Comment: Did you find out the reason for the slight hitch? I am having one too.